# Javascript variable becoming undefined in promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node.js application that syncs client data from an external CRM into by applications database.

The application triggers a CRON job every half an hour to and essentially pulls through the client data via the CRM's API.  This 'sync' code has to make an extremely large amount of calls in order to collect all the data needed.

The calls to the API are made using promises are often using the Promise.all function to execute multiple promises in an async manor.

A simplified section of my code is shown below.  The promise.all method is used to make calls to the *processReferrals* method for each client in my database

```
return db.entities.clients.findAll({ where: {company: company.id}}).then((theClients) => {

        var changes = [];

          var rPromises = [];

          theClients.forEach(client => {
            rPromises.push(CharityLogService.processReferrals(client,company));
          });
          return Promise.all(rPromises).then((values) => {
            values.forEach(v => {
              changes.push(v);
            });
            return changes;
          });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
          return [];
      });
```

The *processReferrals* method itself then makes the calls to the external API in order to return 'referral' data.  Each referral has multiple 'actions', so this method also has nested calls to another method, again via Promises.all

```
processReferrals: function(client,company) {

  var options = {
  uri: "https://externalapi.com/getclientreferrals" + client.id,
  headers: {
    'company': company.id
  },
  json: true
  };

  var actionPromises = [];

  return server.httprequest(options)
  .then(function (referrals) {

  referrals.forEach(referral => {

    actionPromises.push(Service.ActionPromiseMethod(referral.id,company));
  })

  return Promise.all(actionPromises).then((actiondata) => {
        return actiondata;
      });
})
.catch(function (err) {

  console.log('ERROR: api fail error: " + err);

  var changes = {};
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    changes.clientId = client.id;

    console.log("returning changes API FAIL..");
    resolve(changes);
  });

});
}
```

This approach worked fine on in a development environment with a fairly small amount of data.  However, when this was deployed to a live environment with a lot of data (and subsequently a lot more API calls) I encountered issues.

The code seems to work intermittently, successfully returning data for some clients and then failing with the following error message for others

> ERROR: api fail error: client is not defined

I'm a little puzzled how the *client* object can become undefined here.

I'm hosting my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EC2).  I'm not entirely sure this is a code issue as the result is intermittent, and is 100% successful on the dev environment.

Could my AWS instance need upscaling/upgrading due to the sheer amount of calls the need to be made on the live environment?

Any pointers here would be great.

Comment: Why are you using `.forEach`. You could simplify your code a lot by using `.map`. The `Promise.all` result does not event need to be mapped, you could directly return it.

Comment: Plz tidy up the code and use `.map` As for the error, `client is not defined` doesn't mean that client is `undefined` but that it wasn't declared.... Check if you try to access `client` in `Service.ActionPromiseMethod`

Comment: Thanks for the comments . I agree that .map could be used in a few places in my code.  However, its still not the cause of the undeclared 'client' variable problem.  I'm actually not using the 'client' variable anywhere in the Service.ActionPromiseMethod method, hence why I'm puzzled by the error message.